# Undefined index: do in

Tags: php

I am trying to install a arcade script and keep getting these errors, can anyone help out?

> Notice: Undefined index: do in C:\xampp\htdocs\meggiemoos\arcade\install\new.php on line 34
>
> Notice: Use of undefined constant sql - assumed 'sql' in C:\xampp\htdocs\meggiemoos\arcade\install\new.php on line 34
>
> Notice: Undefined index: do in C:\xampp\htdocs\meggiemoos\arcade\install\new.php on line 37
>
> Notice: Use of undefined constant sql2 - assumed 'sql2' in C:\xampp\htdocs\meggiemoos\arcade\install\new.php on line 37

This is line 34 to 38

```
<? if ($_GET['do'] == sql) {
include ('sql1.php');
}
else if ($_GET['do'] == sql2) {
include ('sql2.php');
```

I have tried `if isset($_GET` but I might have done it wrong as of the closed bracket `{` for next line, I was told to add another bracket as well but never told where.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Oh this is a mess.  `sql, sql2` look like they should be quoted strings `'sql','sql2'`

Comment: Yeah, I wouldn't use this script.

Comment: You want `if (isset($_GET['do'])) {...}`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
if (isset($_GET['do']) && $_GET['do'] == 'sql')
```

Answer (score 0):

`sql` by itself is nothing to PHP. You need to have it as a string or variable, as follows:

```
<? if ($_GET['do'] == "sql") {
```

or

```
$var = "sql";
<? if ($_GET['do'] == $var) {
```

As for the line 37 error, the server cannot find the GET variable named 'do', so you need to find out why it's not being set. You might consider adding this to earlier parts of your script:

```
if (!isset($_GET['do'])) {
   exit("do variable was not set!");
}
else {
   $do = $_GET['do'];
}
```

That way, you don't have to keep typing `$_GET['do']`, which can get tedious.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but my guess is because you didn't add `isset`

Comment: Upvoted to offset, it didn't deserve a downvote IMO, but Paul is probably correct.

Comment: I solved it by doing it like this   <? if(isset($_GET['do']) && $_GET['do'] == 'sql') {
include ('sql1.php');
}
else if(isset($_GET['do']) && $_GET['do'] == 'sql2') {
include ('sql2.php');
}, however when installing said creating database and now i have a blank page so yes giving up on this as old script and try a newer one , thanks anyway